# What happens to a double variable when %d is used in a printf?

Tags: c, int, double

So today my class teacher give us 3 problems and said to research at home.. I try hard to get the solution. But there is no exact article about it.

The code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    double x = 2.3;

    printf("%d\n", x);
    printf("%d, x\n");
    printf("%d\n", "x");
}
```

The output is:

- 1717986918
- 1717986918, x
- 4206639

I know i need to use %lf for double. But i want to know what is the problem when i used %d.
I think there is memory problem ( 4bit to 8bit) or garbage. But i want to know more details about the problem. its an assignment.
TIA

Comment: You did an obviously wrong thing.  Your teacher knows it's wrong.  You know it's wrong.   Sure enough, your program went wrong.  UB, QED.

Comment: You're wrong about needing to use `%lf` for a `double`, although you would need to use `%Lf` for a `long double`. (There isn't a `printf` conversion specifier for a `float` because a value of type `float` used as one of `printf`'s optional arguments is automatically converted to `double` by the _default argument promotions_.)

Answer (score 4):

> What happens to a double variable when %d is used in a printf?

Undefined behavior. You're not supposed to misuse the format specifiers for printf.

So anything from it working fine to a program crash with SIGSEGV is a possibility.

What will most likely happen is that it tries to treat your `double` as an `int`, and depending on how your OS saves these, garbage will print.

Comment: So how this value came from?

Comment: @HabiburRahman Who knows? Undefined behavior is undefined. Wondering about what happens with undefined behavior is pointless. Point is, the C standard doesn't mandate how double and float data type data is actually stored in binary. Considering that, trying to treat it like an integer is a gamble, that may or may not work, or may do something completly different instead.

Answer (score 3):

As other people said, this is clearly undefined behavior but let's see one by one.

- In the first case, you're asking to print an integer and you provide a double. This is undefined behavior, so is the result. It may change each time you launch the program.
- Second case you're telling printf "Hey I'm going to give you an integer", and you don't. This lead to another undefined behavior : printf displays something unknown somewhere in the memory.
- Third is like the first case but x is enclosed by double-quote. Double-quote means in C/C++ character-chain, handled by the char* type. So as the first case, you're providing wrong type to printf which lead one more time to undefined behavior.

The way it is handled depends on your printf implementation. As it is for any undefined behavior : just avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

As others said, it is an undefined behavior.

If you want to know how this value came. Double values are encoded using IEEE-754 standard. Use [this converter](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?decimal=050046051) to see how `2.3` looks in memory. It is `01000000 00000010 01100110 01100110
01100110 01100110 01100110 01100110` in bin, or `0x4002666666666666` hex. As size of `int` is `4` and size of `duoble` is 8 (usually it so, it may differ on other platforms).

So we take `0x40026666` and `0x66666666` values, because one of them will be used by `printf`. We see `0x66666666` is 1717986918 in decimal.

That is how you got the first `1717986918`, I cannot imagine how you received second one, maybe because of types sizes mismatch stack wasn't properly cleaned and it printed the same value again.

And about `4206639` it is even more complicated situation, you passed pointer to string, as `"x"` is string and `'x'` is char that can be casted to `int`. So your pointer was treated as `int` and it was printed, this value should differ on every program launch. Also stack corruption may affect this value as well.

Anyway, it is an undefined behavior, so you should never do that. And you may get different results depending on `printf` implementations with different compiler.