# Why C gave a weird output when adding floats and integers?

Tags: c

I am learning C right now and I understand that I can't add an integer with a decimal like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
printf("%d",15+9.0);
  return 0;
```

However when running this I expected some sort of an error. Instead, I got a weird output:

```
-1866308488
```

Can someone help me understand why it gave me this output?

Comment: *Can someone help me understand why it gave me such an output?* -- You lied to `printf` and gave it a `double` instead of an `int` when you specified the `%d` format specifier.

Comment: The `%d` format specifier expects an `int`.  If you pass a `double`, it will not extract and interpret the argument correctly.  Use `%f` or `%g` to format a `double`.

Comment: *I understand that I can't add an integer with a decimal*  No, that's not true.  You absolutely *can* add an integer and a floating-point number like `9.0`.  But the result is a floating-point number, so you must print it using `%f` or `%e`.  `%d` is for printing integers.

Comment: If your compiler didn't give you a warning like `warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'double'`, but should either increase the warning level on your compiler, or get a better compiler.

Comment: @TomKarzes Thank you for the advice really appreciate it. However I know that the format specifier was incorrect. I was wondering why it gave me that huge integer instead of an error of some sort on the console. If you could explain that to me, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: @RishabGhosh As undefined behavior, it's difficult to know exactly what it did, since it depends on the argument passing conventions of your particular architecture.  One possibility is that it extracted a portion of your `double` value, then proceeded to interpret that as an integer.  If integers are smaller than doubles, then it only used a portion of that double value.  That's one explanation for what you saw.  If you aren't familiar with floating point formats, look up the encoding of an IEEE 64-bit value.

Comment: @RishabGhosh *I was wondering why it gave me that huge integer instead of an error of some sort* -- The C language does not do this error checking.  If it did, it would slow the code down.   The C language trusts that what you are doing is correct -- there is no handholding, unlike other languages.  If you want to check for mismatched arguments with format specifiers, that is a job for the compiler or third-party static analysis tools to point out the error at compile-time.

Comment: @TomKarzes Thank you so much for the information. I will definitely look into it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie. Thank you as well for the additional insight into this error.

Answer (score 1):

As @PaulMcKenzie said, C expected an `int` based on the `%d` format specifier. You gave it a double instead. C often gives unexpected behavior instead of throwing an error like Java or C#. [What happens to a double variable when %d is used in a printf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35065124/what-happens-to-a-double-variable-when-d-is-used-in-a-printf) says that the resulting behavior is undefined and OS-specific.